# Gradle error when adding firebase

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have a problem in gradle when I am adding firebase or google ads:

[image: here is the error].

Also you can check the code from gradle below. What am I missing?

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jnugzar"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')


    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'


    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'



}
```

Comment: please help me..

Comment: Did you read the link shown in your IDE?

Comment: i dont now, im just started android studio )

Comment: At the bottom of your screenshot there is a link that tells you what's wrong.

Comment: @NugoJaparidze had similar problem too, update your ads library and add firebase core too, check my answer

Comment: @NugoJaparidze i fix it check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Add **implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'** in Module Gradle 
and In Root gradle make sure you have setup properly

```
buildscript {

     repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
      }
    dependencies {
      classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


     // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
     // in the individual module build.gradle files
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
 }
```

Comment: I try but same problem

Answer (score 1):

Just update your firebase to the latest version (update **firebase-ads**) and add firebase-core, for version you can check [this link](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android):

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'
```

And make sure you are using these:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

Try this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jnugzar"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')


    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.1.1'

    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'


    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'

}
```

And:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: i update grandle but same problem    (implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'   )

Comment: same problem  with       implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

Comment: @NugoJaparidze update your question and post code not image so we can help you

Comment: @NugoJaparidze is this fix your problem?

Comment: yes .thank you very much friend. im traing to create quiz apps for education ))

Comment: @NugoJaparidze perfect accept my answer and upvote if it is useful. Have a nice coding day!

Answer (score 0):

my gradle sync gets error when adding the firebase to project and i have solved my problem with adding this lines to gradle.properties :

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

and adding firebase.core to my module gradle dependencies